# Installation of GNOME Shell Extensions does not ask for root password

Tags: 18.04, root, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Previously, I remember that when I was trying to install a GNOME shell extension, Ubuntu 18.04 asked for the root password.  Today, I found that it does not ask for the root password any more while installing using the website [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

How can I make it to ask for the root password?

Comment: @pomsky yes. Using the website https://extensions.gnome.org/

Answer (score 2):

Installing extensions from the website [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) doesn't ask for your password, it installs extensions locally to your `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory.

If you want to install an extension system-wide, then download the correct package for the extension from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and then extract the package to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory with root privilege.

Alternatively, you may install the extension using `apt` with root privilege if it is available in Ubuntu repos by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-<EXTENSION-NAME>
```

e.g.

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-move-clock
```